# Calculating indegree of each vertex in adjacency list graph in C

Tags: c

I have a graph implemented using adjacency list representation. I want to count number of edges that point to each vertex (indegree of vertex).

Here's a graph:

```
Vertex 0: 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 1: 4 -> 
Vertex 2: 6 -> 1 -> 5 -> 4 -> 
Vertex 3: 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 0 -> 
Vertex 4: 6 -> 2 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 5: 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 6 -> 4 -> 1 -> 
Vertex 6: 0 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1 ->
```

The code I created does not calculate number of links correctly and output the following:

```
Vertex 0: 2
Vertex 1: 0
Vertex 2: 0
Vertex 3: 1
Vertex 4: 2
Vertex 5: 0
Vertex 6: 2
```

Whereas the number of links should be the following for this example:

```
Vertex 0: 3
Vertex 1: 5
Vertex 2: 4
Vertex 3: 3
Vertex 4: 5
Vertex 5: 3
Vertex 6: 4
```

I think I might be missing a switch to the next node in my code? How can I fix this?

Graph structure:

```
typedef struct graph {
    int numberV;
    int numberE;
    struct vertex **adjList;
} GraphT; 

typedef struct vertex {
    int vertex;
    struct vertex *next; 
} VertexT;
```

Code for counting:

```
int countIncomingLinks(GraphT *graph, int vertex) {
    int count = 0;
    GraphT *current = graph;

    for (int i = 0; i < graph->numberV; i++) {
        if (current->adjList[i]->vertex == vertex) {
            count++; 
        }
        // current = current->adjList[i]->next; 
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    ...
    int incoming[vertices]; 

    for (int j = 0; j < vertices; j++) {
        incoming[j] = countIncomingLinks(graph, j); 
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < vertices; j++) {
        printf("Vertex %d: %d\n", j, incoming[j]); 
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actualy you are counting only how many times each vertex apear on head of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`countIncomingLinks` contains one loop that iterates `i` through the indices for the vertices in the graph.

Each vertex contains a list of vertices it has outgoing edges to. You need another loop that, for each vertex iterated through by the first loop, iterates through the outgoing edges of that vertex and, for each outgoing edge that points to the target vertex, adds 1 to the count.

Comment: I would suggest a 'while loop' while vertex->next != NULL inside 'for loop'